# Does Google Spanner support these SQL Commands: Delete, Insert, Update?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Does Google Spanner support SQL-2011? 
I did not find any examples or documentation of the SQL Commands: Delete, Insert and Update.

Answer (score 1):

It only supports a subset, such as DDL to create tables, and queries. Adding data is done via a language sdk (using C#, Go, Java, Node.js, PHP, Python, or Ruby - see the bottom of the [Getting Started with Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/quickstart-console) docs for links to each one), via the Console, or via the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-started/rest/).

Answer (score 0):

At this time, Google Cloud Spanner does not support DML (data manipulation language).

I cannot find an authoritative source. However, other than personal knowledge I have the following quote from the quizlet blog:

https://quizlet.com/blog/quizlet-cloud-spanner

> Cloud Spanner doesn't, however, support data manipulation language (DML) statements. DML includes SQL queries like INSERT and UPDATE. Instead, Spanner's interface definition includes RPCs for mutating rows given their primary key.

I also have the fact that the JAVA jdbc driver does not support it:

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/partners/drivers

> Can I use these drivers to issue Data Manipulation Language (DML) and Data Definition Language (DDL) statements?
>   At present, the drivers do not support DML or DDL statements.

Answer (score 0):

A Google Spanner paper presented at SIGMOD 2017 states:

"The Spanner query processor implements a dialect of SQL,
called Standard SQL, that is shared by several query subsystems
within Google (e.g., Dremel/BigQuery OLAP systems2
). Standard
SQL is based on standard ANSI SQL, fully using standard features
such as ARRAY and row type (called STRUCT) to support nested
data as a first class citizen "

I think the  quote above is correct.

The documentation excerpted below is a FALSE CLAIM that Google should remove:

If you do not support, update, insert and delete SQL you are not ANSI 1992 SQL compliant. Ansi 2011 has a lot of features including querying a DB, "AS OF" a particular timestamp.

I am sure Spanner could become ANSI SQL 2011 compliant with some deviations, but right now it is not ANSI 2011 compliant.

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/

"Cloud Spanner is a fully managed, mission-critical, relational database service that offers transactional consistency at global scale, schemas, SQL (ANSI 2011 with extensions), and automatic, synchronous replication for high availability."

Comment: https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/46103.pdf  Link to a recent paper. Clearly not ANSI SQL compliant.